# Does a timebased workflow remain in queue after the criteria has become false?

Tags: leads, exception, lead-conversion, time-dependent-workflow

I do have a time based workflow set on leads and when we try to convert them it throws an error

> RECORD_IN_USE_BY_WORKFLOW, Unable to convert lead that is in use by workflow:

To overcome this i will be making an update on the record to make the entry criteria to fail in workflow.

My question is that when the time based workflow is put in a queue, will it be removed from queue if the criteria becomes false.

In my workflow i have the `Evaluation Criteria`

```
Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, yes, if the object is in a time-based queue, and its criteria changes to no longer fire that rule, it will be removed.

Longer answer, <strike>[this article](http://www.opfocus.com/2011/08/how-to-convert-a-lead-in-use-by-a-time-based-workflow-in-salesforce/)</strike> details the common approaches to the problem you're seeing and may give you some ideas for other solutions to the problem.

Comment: That link is no longer valid, but I think this is the same article: http://opfocus.com/how-to-convert-a-lead-in-use-by-a-time-based-workflow-in-salesforce/